# Allow traffic on AWS windows instance with flask restful

Tags: python, windows, amazon-web-services, flask, firewall

I created a aws windows instance (linux is sadly no option in this particular case) on which i deployd a python script using flask-restful.

I added inbount traffic rules to allow http traffic on port 80. 
The Flask api is being hostet on host=0.0.0.0, port=80 and debug is False. 
The api is reachable via browser on the server running it.

Sadly im not able to reach the api from external servers. I thought it might be a internal issue between public and internal ip so i tryd reverse proxing that with nginx with no result as well.

Does somebody have an idea what i could do.

Comment: Are there any firewalls on the instance? Also is it running in a pubic subnet?

Comment: Oh well as it seems i forgot about windows defender. Works now ! ty alot.

Comment: Glad to hear. I will make answer for future reference if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, the issue was **windows firewall**.

**The solution** was to allow the connection in the firewall.